# Automatically update a list with objects in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lifecycle

How do I automatically update a list with objects when I add a new object to it? 
I have the Your Past Entries of activities list as in photo example and I need to update it every time I *Add Activity*. For now, the element added appear only if I refresh the browser's page. I have the objects from the database. So when I add an element, firstly it is added to database.

[image]

I hope I was clear enough and you can help me guys.

```
onClick={this.handleUpdateSubmit} is the function which update the list
```

Here is my code

```
class UserDashboard extends React.Component {

state = {
    uid: this.props.userDetails.uid,
    page: 1,
    redirect: false,
    target: 15,
    selectedRole: 4,
    selectedSourceRole: 1,
    quote_nr: '',
    source_id: '',
    status_id: '',
    errorMessage: '',
    message: '',
    cost: '',
    rebate: '',
    pageLoading: false,
    date: '2222-01-02',
    therapists:[],
    globalTargets:[],
    follows:[],
    weekly:[],
    utc: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' '),
}

topProfilesUrl = 'therapists/top/profiles';
getGlobalTargets = 'owner/targets';
followActivities = 'user/follow/activities';
weeklyTarget= 'user/weekly/leads';

componentDidMount = () => {
    const { getActivities,getFollowActivities,getTarget } = this;
    getActivities();
    getFollowActivities();
    getTarget();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}


UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps = (newProps) => {
    let apiDat = newProps.apiDat;
    let apiData = newProps.apiData;
    if (this.props.apiData !== newProps.apiData) {
        if (apiData.activities && apiData.activities.success) {
            let therapists = apiData.activities.therapists;
            let hasMore = true;
            console.log("unu")

            if (therapists.length < 10) {
                hasMore = false;
            }

            this.setState(() => ({
                therapists: this.state.therapists.concat(therapists),
                hasMore: hasMore,
                pageLoading: false
            }))
        }
    }
    if (this.props.apiData !== newProps.apiData) {
        if (apiData.leads && apiData.leads.success) {
            let weekly = apiData.leads.weekly;
            let hasMore = true;
            console.log("unu")

            this.setState(() => ({
                weekly: this.state.weekly.concat(weekly),
                hasMore: hasMore,
                pageLoading: false
            }))
        }
    }

    if (this.props.apiDat !== newProps.apiDat) {

        if (apiDat.targets && apiDat.targets.success) {
            console.log("doi")

            let globalTargets = apiDat.targets.globals;
            let hasMore = true;
            if (globalTargets.length < 10) {
                hasMore = false;
            }

            this.setState(() => ({
                globalTargets: this.state.globalTargets.concat(globalTargets),
            }))
        }
    }
    if (this.props.apiData !== newProps.apiData) {
        if (apiData.followActivities && apiData.followActivities.success) {
            console.log("trei")

            let follows = apiData.followActivities.follows;
            let hasMore = true;
            if (follows.length < 10) {
                hasMore = false;
            }

            this.setState(() => ({
                follows: this.state.follows.concat(follows),
            }))
        }
    }
}
getTarget = () => {
    this.setState({pageLoading: true}, () => { this.loadTargets() })
}

loadTargets = () => {
    console.log("load")
    this.props.actions.reqGetGlobalTargets({
        body: {},
        headers: null,
        resource: `${this.getGlobalTargets}?page=${this.state.page}`
    })
}

getFollowActivities= () => {
    this.setState({pageLoading: true}, () => { this.loadFollowActivities() })
}
loadFollowActivities = () => {
    console.log("load")
    this.props.actions.reqGetFollowActivities({
        body: {},
        headers: null,
        resource: `${this.followActivities}?page=${this.state.page}`
    })
}
renderLeads = () => {
    return (
        this.state.globalTargets.slice(0,1).map( (t, idx) => (
            t.daily_leads
        ))
    )
}
renderSales = () => {
    return (
        this.state.globalTargets.slice(0,1).map( (t, idx) => (
            t.daily_sales
        ))
    )
}
renderRatio = () => {
    return (
        this.state.globalTargets.slice(0,1).map( (t, idx) => (
            t.close_ratio
        ))
    )
}
weeklyLeads = () => {
    const nr = this.state.weekly.map( (t, idx) => (
        t.Leads||0
    ))
    return nr;
}
weeklySales = () => {
    const nr = this.state.weekly.map( (t, idx) => (
        t.Sales||0
    ))
    return nr;
}
getActivities = () => {
    this.setState({pageLoading: true}, () => { this.loadActivities() })
}

loadActivities = () => {
    this.props.actions.reqGetTherapistsTopProfiles({
        body: {},
        headers: null,
        resource: `${this.topProfilesUrl}?uid=${this.state.uid}`
    })
}
renderActivities = () => {
    const items = this.state.therapists.map( (t, idx) => (
        <tr key={t.id} className="activity-display-table">
            <td>Quote Nr.: {t.quote_nr}</td>
            <td>Source: {t.source_id}</td>
            <td>Status: {t.status_id}</td>
            <td>Cost: ${t.cost}</td>
            <td>Rebate: ${t.rebate}</td>
            <td>Date: {t.date.slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-')}</td>
        </tr>
    ))
    return (
        <div ref={0} className="therapist-list">
            <h2>Your Past Entries: </h2>
            { items }
        </div>
    )
}

renderFollowActivities = () => {
    const items = this.state.follows.map( (t, idx) => (
        <tr key={t.id} className="activity-display-table">
            <td>Quote Nr.: {t.quote_nr}</td>
            <td>Source: {t.source_id}</td>
            <td>Status: {t.status_id}</td>
            <td>Cost: ${t.cost}</td>
            <td>Rebate: ${t.rebate}</td>
            <td>Date: {t.date.slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-')}</td>
        </tr>
    ))
    return (

        <div ref={0} className="therapist-list">
            { items }
        </div>

    )
}
getleads = () =>{
    const id = "Lead";
    const dd =  this.state.utc.slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-');
    const count = this.state.therapists.filter((t) => t.status_id === id && t.date.slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-')===dd).length;
    const nb = this.state.therapists.filter((t) => t.date.slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-') === dd).length;

   // console.log(count);
    //console.log(nb);
    //console.log(dd);
    return count;
}

getsales = () =>{
    const status = "Sold";
    const dd =  this.state.utc.slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-');
    const nr = this.state.therapists.filter((t) => t.status_id === status && t.date.slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-')===dd).length;
 //   const nb = this.state.follows.filter((t) => t.date.slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-') === dd).length;
    console.log(nr);
    return nr;
}
submitUrl = 'registerActivities';
updateUrl = 'updateActivities';

handleChange = (eve) => {

    let inputName = eve.target.name,
        value = eve.target.value;

    this.setState(() => {
        return {[inputName]: value}
    })
}

handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({errors: []}, () => {

        const formValid = this.validateForm()

        if (!formValid) {
            return;
        }

        const acBody = {
            quote_nr: this.state.quote_nr,
            cost: this.state.cost,
            source_id: this.state.selectedSourceRole,
            status_id: this.state.selectedRole,
            date: this.state.utc,
            rebate: this.state.rebate,
            user_id:this.state.uid,
        }
       this.props.actions.reqActionsUsers(acBody, this.submitUrl);
    })
}

handleUpdateSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({errors: []}, () => {

        const formValid = this.validateForm()

        if (!formValid) {
            return;
        }

        const aBody = {
            id: this.state.id,
            quote_nr: this.state.quote_nr,
            cost: this.state.cost,
            source_id: this.state.selectedSourceRole,
            status_id: this.state.selectedRole,
            date: this.state.utc,
            rebate: this.state.rebate,
            user_id:this.state.uid,
        }
        console.log(aBody);
        this.props.actions.reqUpdateAction(aBody, this.updateUrl);
    })
}

validateForm = () => {

    let formValid = true;

    if (this.state.quote_nr === '') {
        formValid = false;
        this.setState( () => ({
            errors: [
                {input: 'quote_nr'}
            ],
            errorMessage: 'Quote Number is mandatory',
        }))
    } else if (this.state.cost === '') {
        formValid = false;
        this.setState( () => ({
            errors: [
                {input: 'cost'}
            ],
            errorMessage: 'Cost is mandatory'
        }))
    } else if (this.state.rebate === '') {
        formValid = false;
        this.setState( () => ({
            errors: [
                {input: 'rebate'}
            ],
            errorMessage: 'Rebate is mandatory'
        }))
    }
    if (formValid === true) {
        this.setState( () => ({
            message: 'You Activity Has Been Added',
            errorMessage: ''
        }))
    }
    return formValid

}

handleStatusChange = (event) => {
    let statusId = event.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({
        selectedRole: statusId
    }))
}

handleSourceChange = (ev) => {
    let statusId = ev.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({
        selectedSourceRole: statusId
    }))
}

render () {
    console.log("weekly",this.weeklyLeads());
    return (

        <MainWrapper>
            <div id="user-dashboard">
                <HeaderUser logoutRedirect="/signin"/>
                <div className="page-background">
                    <SidebarUser page="dashboard"/>
                    {/* Page Content */}
                    <div className="inner-content">
                        <div className="top-row">
                            <h1>Salesperson Dashboard</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="second-row">
                        </div>
                        <div className="activity-table">
                            <table className="a">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Today's Targets ({this.state.utc.slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-')})</th>
                                    <th>Weekly Targets</th>
                                    <th>Bonus So Far This Week</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{this.getleads()}/{this.renderLeads()} Leads Handled</td>
                                    <td>{this.weeklyLeads()}/{this.renderLeads()*5} Leads Handled</td>
                                    <td>$0 From Leads</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{this.getsales()}/{this.renderSales()} Sales</td>
                                    <td>{this.weeklySales()}/{this.renderSales()*5} Sales</td>
                                    <td>$0 From Sales</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>0/{this.renderRatio()} Close Ratio</td>
                                    <td>0/{this.renderRatio()*5} Close Ratio</td>
                                    <td>$0 From Profit Share</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                           <h2>Leads Due For A Followup</h2>
                            { this.renderFollowActivities() }

                        </div>
                        <h2 className="activity">Add Activity</h2>
                        <div className="activity-menu">
                            <input type="text"
                                   placeholder="Quote Number"
                                   name="quote_nr"
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                                 />
                                <select  onChange={this.handleSourceChange}>
                                    <option value="1">Phone</option>
                                    <option value="2">Email</option>
                                    <option value="3">Live Chat</option>
                                </select>
                            <select  onChange={this.handleStatusChange}>
                                <option value="4">Lead</option>
                                <option value="5">Sold</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="text"
                                   placeholder="Cost"
                                   name="cost"
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                            <input type="text"
                                   placeholder={this.state.cost/20||("Recom. Rebate" + " $")}
                                   name="recRebate"
                                   readOnly
                            />
                            <input type="text"
                                   placeholder={this.state.cost/10||("Max Possible Rebate" + " $")}
                                   name="maxRebate"
                                   readOnly
                            />
                            <input type="text"
                                   placeholder="Final Rebate $"
                                   name="rebate"
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <p className="error-message">{this.state.errorMessage}</p>
                        <Popup
                        content={this.state.message}
                        on="click"
                        pinned
                        trigger={

                            <ButtonRoundGradient className="activity_button" text="Add Activity"
                                                 onClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
                        }
                        />
                        <Popup
                            content={"Activity Has Been Updated"}
                            on="click"
                            pinned
                            trigger={
                        <ButtonRoundGradient className="activity_button" text="Update Activity"  onClick={this.handleUpdateSubmit}/>
                            }
                        />
                        { this.renderActivities() }

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </MainWrapper>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: First I recommend to refactor your component into smaller components.

Comment: You can do couple of things for improving UX. Firstly, you can handle the data at the front-end by sending the add request to the backend while at the same time push the object to already displayed array, but the gotcha here will be that the newly added object will be immutable. Secondly, you can add loading state, whenever a user will add an object he/she will have to waiting for the loading state to get to false until then you will put a loading sign there, the data in this case with be mutable one.

Hopefully, It will help.